# half circle text on the edges

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

if I have 2 Sentences and I want each one to be on the edges.. so each sentence look like half circle .. it's possible to do that?

```css
.text{
 background-color: brown;
 height: 200px;
 width: 500px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
    <div class="text">
      <p>this is text one</p>
      <p>this is text two</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: If want this

(this is text one    this is text tow)

Then you add border on p tag

Comment: I would probably go with a technology suited for the problem such as SVG and TextPath. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath